# Typescript dynamic runtime type

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript file containing a list of typed exported functions that looks like that:

```js
// File hooks.tsx
export function useBookQuery(...) {
...
}
export function useAuthorQuery(...) {
...
}
```

I also have a class defined as follow (it stores the various exported function from the previous file and resolve function from a type).

```js
// File TypeRegistry.tsx
class TypeRegistry {
    constructor(hooks) {
        this.hooks = hooks
    }

    getHook(type: string) {
        return this.hooks[`use${type}Query`];
    }
}
```

The class is instanced as follow:

```js
import * as hooks from './hooks'
const typeRegistry = new TypeRegistry(hooks);
const queryBook = typeRegistry.getHook('Book');
const queryAuthor = typeRegistry.getHook('Author');
```

Here, I want the `queryBook` variable type to be the one of the `useBookQuery` from the `hooks.tsx` file and the `queryAuthor` to be the type of `useAuthorQuery`.
I don't know how to type the `getHook` method to achieve the desired behavior and I don't know if it's even possible.

Comment: What does `./hooks` export? A dictionary of sorts?

Comment: The `hooks.tsx` file exports named exports that we can normaly import through `import {useBookQuery} from './hooks'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type this using `typeof import` to get the type of the import. You can then manipulate this type as you would any other. In this case `getHook` will need to be generic, and we will need to use template literal types and conditional types to extract the union of possible values for `type`:

```
// @filename: TypeRegistry.tsx
type AllHooks = typeof import('./hooks');
type ExtractName<T extends `use${string}Query`> =  T extends `use${infer Type}Query` ? Type: never
class TypeRegistry {
    hooks: AllHooks;
    constructor(hooks: AllHooks) {
        this.hooks = hooks
    }

    getHook<K extends ExtractName<keyof AllHooks>>(type: K): AllHooks[`use${K}Query`] {
        return this.hooks[`use${type}Query`];
    }
}

// @filename: usage.tsx
import * as hooks from './hooks'
const typeRegistry = new TypeRegistry(hooks);
const queryBook = typeRegistry.getHook('Book'); // correct type for book
const queryAuthor = typeRegistry.getHook('Author'); // correct type for author
```

[Workbench link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dev/bug-workbench/?ts=4.5.4#code/PTAEAEDMEsBsFMB2BDAtvAXKAFge1wNYDOAdAC5EAeAUNfJQA64BOZokArogMZnS6JQHIvABC+AgEUO8ZgE8AFAEosAb1B8yCLETLNoiAOYBfUKuqhLoZvDIdmgxB1iwAhAG5qxuoxZtOPHwCQiIAghxkeMzSsooqZqAo6Dp6BoagpuZW1rb2js5unt7UIBAwCEmYoAAqcgzwAErwhtC68uRUtGR18KChLgASEkSgALwaPbiQoNCoTKwKAOQkwHiERItKnt31oACilHrIvAByaPAAPNWg9GRIACYjAAbC8AAkqm1pxjHyTwB8Y0s11uD2erw+BkgshqPR+Mj+oAA-LD6lhEPAAG6yajcWDIIgjWr1JotNpyMwWKxrYhYfqwIbrTzZbgCNocXgsBQ0oh0wbDJSU7LZSKtEg8oE8qmWYrZQy2RkEC4AaRuhzB+0OzGOZDO6AuBHgcimfX563+-wUOyqyvi9MVRAA2i8RB9lfDYk8ALpC4WWGx2BwabBinnOiGqa0ev5e5lWbzFUpQOBIc5YYTIeUdGizeZsABUoAJOGG7GYuFQoGWq2Gi1xbLY1tJrT0FPGGIA7qjGs0W-JuQLPKzELpQABHBFycSEIFN3vkkjysiKpbTgibIcN8eT8KRFiznrNhdLleLXdRDdAA)

You can also make `TypeRegistry` generic, so the type of `hooks` can be passed in when you build the registry:

```
type ExtractName<T extends string> =  T extends `use${infer Type}Query` ? Type: never
class TypeRegistry<T extends Record<`use${string}Query`, () => any>> {
    hooks: T;
    constructor(hooks: T) {
        this.hooks = hooks
    }

    getHook<K extends ExtractName<keyof T & string>>(type: K): T[`use${K}Query`] {
        return this.hooks[`use${type}Query`];
    }
}
```

[Workbench link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dev/bug-workbench/?ts=4.5.4#code/PTAEAEDMEsBsFMB2BDAtvAXKAFge1wNYDOAdAC5EAeAUNfJQA64BOZokArogMZnS6JQHIvABC+AgEUO8ZgE8AFAEosAb1B8yCLETLNoiAOYBfUKuqhLoZvDIdmgxB1iwAhAG5qxuoxZtOPHwCQiIAghxkeMzSsooqZqAo6Dp6BoagpuZW1rb2js5unt7UIBAwCEmYoAAqcgzwAErwhtC68uRUtGR18KAAopR6yLwAcmjwADzVoPRkSAAmRKBtaQB8oAC8ltOzC0sABsLwACSqBpCyNT3GMfL7oAD8V-VYiPAAbrLU3LDIREu1epNFptORTGaDPagJrcFjzCaHESnFZGG4yO4AGlAyk262QiDkq3WWSseEIRCw1U82VhiDaHF4LAUZOIlKUZgs2SskVaJBZSy2-M5lmK2UMtgAEhIJgBpCFzRCLfqDZjDMhjdATAjwOS4SA1UAAMmWqSMRIU3ReoBl8WqAG1ESdVDK0bF9gBdDlcqw2OwODTYXn8h1HU6W+Cuu7u6lWbzFUpQOBIcZYYTIcUdGjQVBMVigABUoD+OAkS0gzFwqFAAHISMB+dXvgJdBoesDWno5JtEvAAO7PRrNDvyZmlpTuUBNulsACO6Lk4kI3fD7dBJHFZClhAU1cXBGr46nLbnsXCkRYy7bQ7XG63BB3Z6iB-cQA)

Comment: Thanks! It almost solves my problem. The last part is that `TypeRegistry` is part of a library, so I can't import the hooks file inside it. Is there a way for the `AllHooks` type to be defined at runtime from the hooks property of the TypeRegistry? Or to define it with something like : `type AllHooks = typeof this.hooks`?

Comment: @Vincent added a generic version